# Smoothly stop css infinite animation

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations, infinite

I have a element which has an infinite animation

```
animation: start .75s steps(19) infinite;
```

Now after a some time (this time changes) I would like to stop the animation but so that it smoothly runs out. When I stop the animation via jQuery by removing the animation class it just stops.

I hope you have a idea for this?

Comment: Were you able to figure out any answer for this?

Comment: Read [**my article**](http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/) on CSS-Tricks. There is no easy way to do it but it can be done

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a much simpler way using [Svelte](https://svelte.dev). Say `loading` is a boolean. The animation should run, when `loading` is true. Then we have e.g. a SVG `line` that should jump up and down.

```html
<line id="line-0" class="{animateClass ? 'animate' : ''}" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="20"/>
```

We add the following CSS.

```
line {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

line.animate {
  animation-direction: alternate;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

As you can see, we use single-run transitions. A jump-up transition when the `animate` class is there and a fall-down transition, when the `animate` class is gone.

Now, we need some JavaScript to control for the ups and downs.

```
let animateClass = false;
let intervalId;

function animateLine(loading) {
  if (loading) {
    if (!intervalId) {
      animateClass = true;
      intervalId = setInterval(() => animateClass = !animateClass, 800);
     }
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = null;
    animateClass = false;
  }
}

$: animateLine(loading); // call the function every time loading is updated
```

Each time `loading` changes, the `animateLine` function is called and alternates between jump-up and fall-down transitions. This also guarantees a smooth stop of the animation. Moreover, the animation itself is pure CSS and thus very performant.

Please note that the `setInterval` function handles the callback execution every 800 ms. This is exactly the length of the CSS transitions.

Of course, you can implement this with Vanilla JS, too. However, Svelte delivers some syntactic sugar for reactivity.

See also this [blog post](https://higsch.me/2019/06/25/2019-06-25-smooth-css-transitions/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a this very simple Javascript syntax:

```
function stopAnimation(){

document.getElementById('animationElement').setAttribute('class', 'displayNone');
};
setTimeout(stopAnimation, 5000);
```

the id we're targeting is the one which does the animation and we're giving it a class named 'displayNone' which is in our CSS file.after this we call the the function doing all this after 5 seconds which is when your animation ends. you can change this to whatever time you want your animation to end.

and add this to your CSS:

```
.displayNone{
display: none;
}
```

N.B: make sure to add the css code BEFORE the animation properties or else it wont work